# How to move to certain coordinates and click on the element?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to click to click on the certain element. For that I use `ActionChains` library. 
At first I click on the first element and ewerything works ok. But when I try to move mouse to the next element and click on it I get an error

> selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message:
>   move target out of bounds

Here's the raw example of the code

```
actions = ActionChains(self.sd.driver)
actions.move_by_offset(950, 493).click().perform()
actions.move_by_offset(948, 358).click().send_keys(self.email).perform()
actions.click().perform()
```

Also I've tried such option

```
actions = ActionChains(self.sd.driver)
actions.move_by_offset(950, 493).click().perform()
actions.move_by_offset(0, -135).click().send_keys(self.email).perform()
actions.click().perform()
```

**Important note:** I must use only coordinates, not elements found by xpath etc.

Comment: Are you trying to move the mouse out of the viewport? Does the same error occur if you only move it a small amount? Can you see what happens (in the browser) between those elements?

Comment: No, I'm not moving mouse out of viewport, just trying to move it a little bit to click on other element. Same error occures if I try to move mouse a little. In the browser I can't see what happens.

Comment: Please provide the html of the element. xpath is not the only way.

Comment: I've tried css, class name etc. Didn't work. But here's an element

`<input aria-invalid="false" class="wyq iyn Hsu aZc tBJ dyH iFc SMy yTZ L4E edc pBj qJc fgH" id="email" name="id" placeholder="email address" type="email" value=>`